# TIOCEXCL in Delphi

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm converting some old comport code for MacOS from C++ Builder to Delphi 10.4

```
if (ioctl(handle, TIOCEXCL) == -1)
{
    close(handle);
    return false;
}
```

But TIOCEXCL doesn't seem to be defined in Delphi, is it safe to assume that TIOCEXCL that's defined as _IO('t',13) always is $2000740D

Comment: TIOCEXCL should be $540C, at least according to Linuxapi.KernelIoctl.pas, and this: https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctls.h.html, assuming it's the same on macOS

Comment: @DaveNottage MacOS is based on FreeBSD, not Linux. FreeBSD [does define](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/master/sys/sys/ttycom.h) `TIOCEXCL` as `_IO('t',13)`, which is equal to 0x2000740D.